# Не работает e.onerror в Firefox

Tags: javascript, отладка

- Этот скрипт скрывает родительский блок, если в нем не **прогружено
  src изображения**
- работает во всех браузерах кроме **Firefox**

Это баг Firefox или дело в скрипте? **Если дело в скрипте, то как заставить скрипт работать в Firefox?**

P.S.
Этой ошибки не видно на этом сайте. Попробуйте локально у себя на пк создать файл **index.htm**l и туда вставить этот код, затем посмотрите результат через Firefox.

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.Parent_block > .Child_Img');

images.forEach(function(e) {
e.onerror = function() {
e.closest('.Parent_block').style.display = 'none';
};
});
```

```css
.Parent_block {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
}

img {
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure class="Parent_block">
<img class="Child_Img" src="">
<figcaption class="Img_text">1</figcaption>
</figure>


<figure class="Parent_block">
<img class="Child_Img" src="https://i.ibb.co/kyXhZmB/photo-2021-11-18-14-40-18.jpg">
<figcaption class="Img_text">2</figcaption>
</figure>


<figure class="Parent_block">
<img class="Child_Img" src="">
<figcaption class="Img_text">3</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить `return true`

```
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.Parent_block > .Child_Img');

images.forEach(function(e) {
    e.onerror = function() {
        e.closest('.Parent_block').style.display = 'none';
        return true;
    };
});
```

Этот ответ нашел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008692/window-onerror-not-firing-in-firefox), возможно там что-то еще есть полезное для вас

[ВОТ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) еще какая-то статья